# How to put php echo array into input tag?

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a problem to put `<?php echo $myArray[0] === 'true' ? 'checked' : ''; ?>` into `<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val" value="1" >` . Because I need to define checked in the input. Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem.

Below is my sample code, but cannot work:

```
<?php

    $check_value = 'true,false,false,false,true,false,false';
    
    
    $myArray = explode(',', $check_value);

    foreach ($myArray as $k => $va) { 
    }
    
    
    foreach ($result_arr_user as $val_user) {
    $checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val" value="1" echo $myArray[0] === 'true' ? 'checked' : ''; >&nbsp;';
    }
?>
```

Comment: what does `$result_arr_user` contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply re-write input checkbox as

```php
$checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox_val' name='checkbox_val' value='1' ".($myArray[0] === "true" ? "checked" : "")." >";
```

Loop

```php
<?php

   $check_value = 'true,false,false,false,true,false,false';
   $myArray = explode(',', $check_value);   
   for ($i = 0; $i <= count($myArray); $i++) {
     $checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox_val' name='checkbox_val' value='1' ".($myArray[$i] === "true" ? "checked" : "")." >";
     echo $checkbox;
   } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks your answer. If I want to use $i to replace 0, do you know how to do it? I use this method cannot word $checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox_val' name='checkbox_val' value='1'".($myArray[$i] === "true" ? "checked" : "")." >";

Comment: Check the updated answer for this comment answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $check_value = 'true,false,false,false,true,false,false';
    
      $myArray = explode(',', $check_value);
     
    
    foreach ( $myArray  as $val_user) {
        if($val_user=='true')
        {
        
    $checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val" value="1"  checked="true">';
        }   
        else
        {
             $checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val" value="1" >';
            
        }
   }
?>
```

You can simply write in this way

Comment: input tag checked is a property not attribute. So checked="true" and checked="false" are same.

Comment: So remove checked="false" from else condition updating the code